# test listItem using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, jestjs

I am jest beginner, stuck with this test, for example inside 'ListItem' I have 'click me' when that is clicked under that will come 'cameras' dropdown, so if I should check what happens when 'click me' is clicked or what it contains.  At the moment with my code I am verifying component to be there(this works). and under that i have a code of when clicking that 'ListItem' where it gives me 'TypeError: elem.click is not a function'

```js
import {
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemText,
  ListItemSecondaryAction,
  Collapse,
  IconButton,
  MenuItem,
} from "@material-ui/core/";
export const SelectionList:

interface SelectionList {
  actionArgs?: string | undefined;
  onUpdateClick: (e: any) => void;
  onDeleteClick: (e: any) => void;
  onDetailsClick: (e: any) => void;
  action: string;
  name?: string;
  identifier?: string;
  classes: {
    button_basic: string;
    formControl: string;
    selectionCard: string;
  };
}

React.FC<SelectionList> = (
  props
) => {
  const itemListCollapseKey = props.action + "-itemlist-collapse";
  const [collapseStates, setCollapseStates] = useState({
    [itemListCollapseKey]: false,
  });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleExpandClick = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>,
    key: string
  ) => {
    setCollapseStates({
      ...collapseStates,
      [key]: !collapseStates[key],
    });
  };

  const listItems = (
    key: React.Key | null | undefined,
    content: SelectionList | undefined | string,
    element: SelectionList
  ) => {
    return (
      <MenuItem
        key={key}
        selected={isElementSelected(element)}
        button
        onClick={(event) => {
          selectElement(element);
        }}
      >
        <ListItemText primary={content} key={key + "-litext"}></ListItemText>
        <ListItemSecondaryAction
        // p={1}
        >
          <IconButton
            onClick={(e) => handleDetailsClick(e, element)}
            aria-label="details"
          >
          </IconButton>
        </ListItemSecondaryAction>
      </MenuItem>
    );
  };

  

  let childList: React.ReactElement | string = "";
  if (data && data.length > 0) {
    childList = (
      <Collapse
        key={itemListCollapseKey}
        in={collapseStates[itemListCollapseKey]}
        unmountOnExit
      >
        {data.map((el) => (
          <List key={keyFromEl(el) + "sublist"}>
            {listItems(keyFromEl(el), el.name, el)}
          </List>
        ))}
      </Collapse>
    );
  }

  return (
    <List component="div" data-testid="SelectionListt">
      <ListItem
        key={props.action + "-header"}
        button
        onClick={(event) => {
          handleExpandClick(event, itemListCollapseKey);
        }}
      >
        click me
      </ListItem>

      {childList}
    </List>
  );
};
```

My testing:

```js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";

function handleUpdateClick(event: any, type = "") {}
test("test", () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SelectionList
        classes={{ button_basic: "", formControl: "", selectionCard: "" }}
        action={"cameras"}
        actionArgs={""}
        onUpdateClick={handleUpdateClick}
        onDeleteClick={handleUpdateClick}
        onDetailsClick={handleUpdateClick}
      />
    </Provider>
  );
  const SelectionCardElement = screen.getByTestId("SelectionListt");
  expect(SelectionCardElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

here i want to click the 'ListItem'

```js
it.todo("list item renders");
it("list item triggers click callback when clicked", () => {
  const onClickCallback = jest.fn();
  const elem = render(<ListItem onClick={onClickCallback} />);
  elem.click();
  expect(onClickCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

i want to check what happens when 'click me' is clicked or what it contains how should i proceed from this?
Dropdown comes because of this '{childList}', so if it gets changed in my code test should not pass

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the `click` function on the render. You need to use [fireEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/) or the [userEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event) helpers.

Example:

```
it("list item triggers click callback when clicked", () => {
  const onClickCallback = jest.fn();
  const elem = render(<ListItem onClick={onClickCallback}>Click me</ListItem>);
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Click me'))
  expect(onClickCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: would you have a suggestion of how to accomplish that, using those codes i provided ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the example.

Comment: could you possibly also provide connecting part, where it is connected to <SelectionList/> component, at the moment it just passes the test and not connected to anything, dropdown comes because of this '{childList}', so if it gets changed in my code test should not pass

Comment: You can just replace the ListItem component with the SelectionList:
```
 const elem = render(<SelectionList onClick={onClickCallback}>Click me</ListItem>);
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Click me'))
  expect(onClickCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```
Now you have access to the whole SelectionList component and you can query for the nested elements, e.g. you can use `data-testid` attr to recognize the nested components:
`screen. getByTestId('example-id')` = will give you access to the nested component.
I'm not sure how you're passing the data for the rendering nested components

Comment: Could you provide the working example with codesandbox?

Comment: test("test", () => {render(<Provider store={store}><SelectionList classes={{ button_basic: "", formControl: "",selectionCard: ""}} action={"cameras"} onUpdateClick={handleUpdateClick} const SelectionCardElement = screen.getByTestId("SelectionListt"); expect(SelectionCardElement).toBeInTheDocument();
it("list item triggers click callback when clicked", () => {
const onClickCallback = jest.fn(); const elem = render(<SelectionList onClick={onClickCallback}>Click me</ListItem>);  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Click me')) expect(onClickCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);});});

Comment: something is wrong with that ?

Comment: isnt this part wrong '<SelectionList onClick={onClickCallback}>Click me</ListItem>' onclick should be on 'ListItem' and 'ListItem' is inside 'SelectionList' component